# How to create a background process like Facebook App, Gmail or Ymail did

Tags: android, mysql, facebook, process, background

Hi guys I just want to ask on how to create a background process on Android that automatically pull a data on database when a certain data changes. Just like Facebook app did, it automatically notifies you when a new message or notification arrived. Or just like a Gmail or Ymail app that it automatically notifies you when you have a new message.

By the way, my database is MySql.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to make use of Service for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) if you want something to run in background. What you want to implement is [call back](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) from the server. If you want to give notifications on something like sms or mms etc then the call back is already implemented through [content observers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html). Call backs can also be build through custom content observer.

Comment: great! this worth a try :)

Answer (score 3):

**Answer for local on device database:**
If the database is on the phone just override the crud methods of the database helper to fire off an intent for your apps.  You don't need a service to do that.

**Answer for database on the interweb:**
Google play services you have the ability to send free unlimited [send to sync message](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#s2s) from a web server to your apps.  Again just override the crud methods on the server and send the message.

**Danger on google play services or any service running on the device**
Users hate services on their devices because they use resources.  I got a review of one on my [1st android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gosylvester.bestrides) because of google play services.  From that I learned to never put a service on a users device.  My worst fear is the user un-installs my app because it uses a service.  But I live with this fear and I've already got my google play service running and it even queues messages for the device if there is no data connection.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Those are called services. You may go through [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html) tutorial to know how you can implement and use it in your app.

Answer (score 0):

When your activity enter on a pause state, the system calls the onPause() method, you must override this method and put what you want to do in background.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using services. Click [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html) for the tutorial which has code and process how to achieve this .

Also here is the link from android developer page. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html